# How do I create a new Webform in Drupal 8?

Tags: webform-civicrm

I have enabled webform and webform civicrm, but I don't see an option to add a webform under content (like in Drupal 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right! In D8 -> look under Structure -> Webforms

```
/admin/structure/webform
```